# How do I set two or more reminders in Office365 Outlook Calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, office365, reminder

Where I work, we use Office-365 Outlook for email and scheduling.  I would like to have a reminder two hours before, and again ten minutes before, a weekly meeting.  I see a drop-down list to set one reminder, but no visible hints as to how to make a second reminder.